# Extract only the characters that are between opening and ending parantheses in the start and end of a string in R

Tags: r, regex, text-extraction, stringr, stringi

I have many strings that all have the following format:

```
mystrings <- c(
  "(ABFUHIASH)THISISAVERYLONGSTRINGWITHOUTANYSPACES(ENDING)",
  "(SECONDSTR)YETANOTHERBORINGSTRINGWITHOUTSPACES(RANDOMENDING)", 
  "(JOWERIC)THISPARTSHOULDNOTBEEXTRACTED(GETTHIS)", 
  "(CAPTURETHIS)IOJSDOIOIADSNCXZZCX(IJFAI)"
)
```

I need to capture the strings that are inside parentheses both at the start and the end of the original `mystrings`.

Therefore, variable `start` will store the starting characters for each of the above strings with the same index. The result will be this:

```
start[1]
ABFUHIASH

start[2]
SECONDSTR

start[3]
JOWERIC

start[4]
CAPTURETHIS
```

And similarly, the ending for each string in `mystrings` will be saved into `end`:

```
end[1]
ENDING

end[2]
RANDOMENDING

end[3]
GETTHIS

end[4]
IJFAI
```

**Parentheses themselves should NOT be captured.**

Is there a way/function to do this quickly in R?

I have tried `stringr::word` and `stringi::stri_extract`, but I am getting very strange results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `stringr` library for this. For example

```
library(stringr)
mm <- str_match(mystrings, "^\\(([^)]+)\\).*\\(([^)]+)\\)$")
mm
```

The match finds the stuff between the parenthesis at the beginning and end of the string in capture groups so they can be easily extracted.

It returns a character matrix, and you seem to just want the 2nd and 3rd column. `mm[,2:3]`

```
     [,1]          [,2]          
[1,] "ABFUHIASH"   "ENDING"      
[2,] "SECONDSTR"   "RANDOMENDING"
[3,] "JOWERIC"     "GETTHIS"     
[4,] "CAPTURETHIS" "IJFAI"
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant, some real regex witchcraft there. I would have never thought such a complicated regex would be required for this task. No wonder my rudimentary regexes (such as `\\(*\\)` were failing all the way to even capture the start!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
> regmatches(mystrings,gregexpr("\\(.+?\\)",mystrings))
[[1]]
[1] "(ABFUHIASH)" "(ENDING)"   

[[2]]
[1] "(SECONDSTR)"    "(RANDOMENDING)"

[[3]]
[1] "(JOWERIC)" "(GETTHIS)"

[[4]]
[1] "(CAPTURETHIS)" "(IJFAI)"
```

E.g., to extract endings you could:

```
lapply(x,tail,1)
```